Show that $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}=\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$
This equation comes from a problem in a textbook, where I was asked to show that
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^n\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$
I adopt a straightforward approach:
$$(1-x^2)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}1^{n-r}(-x^2)^r=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^rx^{2r}$$
and then we can easily get its definite integral, which is
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}x^{2r+1}$$
then
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^n\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}x^{2r+1}\bigg]_0^1=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}$$
and then the remaining problem is to show that
$$\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}=\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$
I've checked their values by geogebra and it appears that this equation is always true, but how can we preceed?

You might be able to find a proof in any of the answers to this question of mine. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1528824/7933
